# Angular2 - PHP - EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0 for URL: null

Tags: php, angularjs

So apprently there are many posts about this, but they all are not really clear to me
some even seems to give an answer in python (???)

I try to access this php file (wamp listening on port 80)

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo '{"test":"test"}';
?>
```

the angular service I call is this one

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService 
{
    constructor(private http:Http) 
    {
    }

```
authenticate = function(login:string, pass:string) : void
{
    this.http.get("http://localhost/data.php")
        .subscribe( 
            (res:any) => 
            {
                console.log('res', res.json());
            }
        );
};
```

}

I get the above error

edit :

```
      <?php
    //header('Content-type: application/json');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');   
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    echo '{"test":"test"}';
?>
```

thanks

Comment: _“people mention CORS, and I have no idea what this is”_ – well go look it up then …? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing // This would only be a CORS issue, if the page the script is running in was loaded from a different address than `http://localhost/` (But if you are not trying to load stuff from a different domain, you should rather be using relative paths to begin with - that makes it less likely you get problems in that regard later, f.e. if you have a site that is reachable via a non-www and a www version of the domain name.)

Comment: I added the cors header but still got the same

Comment: It's on the sever side that you shoud put the Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Well is it even a cross-domain request in the first place, or not? Adding CORS headers in a situation where they are not even applicable is of course not going to achieve anything.

Comment: I dont know, it's all on my local machine and tutorials dont even mention this issue...it has been an eternal question for me so far, if angular/TS runs on port 3000 with the lite server, then how does it access php from a wamp server on the same machine (port 80)?

Comment: I really cant make this work, I send the correct headers from php, but now I get  Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: ok I removed it from the get request headers of course, stupid of me, now it works